# find combinations in arbitrarily nested lists under conditions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I want to find possible paths on a finite grid of points. Say, starting point is (x,y). Then next point (m,n) in the path is given by conditions

1. (m!=x) and (n!=y)  ie. I exclude the row and column I was in previously.
2. n < y      ie. I always hop DOWN.
3. m,n >= 0   ie. all the points are always in first quadrant
4. Stopping criteria is when a point lies on x axis.

Hence, generate all possible combinations of such 'paths' possible.

Following is what I've tried.

```
def lisy(x,y):
    return [(i,j) for i in range(4,0,-1) for j in range(4,0,-1) if(i!=x and j<y)]
```

---

```
def recurse(x,y):
    if (not lisy(x,y)):
        return (x,y)
    else:
        return [(x,y), [recurse(i,j) for i,j in lisy(x,y)]]
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
In [89]: recurse(1,4)
Out[89]: 
[(1, 4),
 [[(4, 3),
   [[(3, 2), [(4, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)]],
    (3, 1),
    [(2, 2), [(4, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1)]],
    (2, 1),
    [(1, 2), [(4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1)]],
    (1, 1)]],
  [(4, 2), [(3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)]],
  (4, 1),
  [(3, 3),
   [[(4, 2), [(3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)]],
    (4, 1),
    [(2, 2), [(4, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1)]],
    (2, 1),
    [(1, 2), [(4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1)]],
    (1, 1)]],
  [(3, 2), [(4, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)]],
  (3, 1),
  [(2, 3),
   [[(4, 2), [(3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)]],
    (4, 1),
    [(3, 2), [(4, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)]],
    (3, 1),
    [(1, 2), [(4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1)]],
    (1, 1)]],
  [(2, 2), [(4, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1)]],
  (2, 1)]]
```

This gives me a nested lists of possible new points from each point.

Can anyone tell me how to process my list obtained from `recurse(1,4)`?

edit1:

Effectively I hop from a given starting point (in a 4x4 grid [finite]), satisfying the three conditions mentioned until stopping criteria is met, ie. `m,n > 0`

Comment: Your question is not clear. All you counting all the restricted paths from one point (x,y) to another given point? Is that point (m,n) any point on the path or the desired end point? Clearly the number of paths that simply start at a given point is infinite and you cannot possible put them all in a list (though an infinite generator is possible). Or do you have an additional restriction on using only points in the first quadrant?

Comment: @Rory : The stopping criteria is `m,n > 0`. ie. in first quadrant. Somehow I assumed this information implicit. My bad. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I'd love to see the generator implementation. Eventually this has to be done in a grid of 1000x1000. So generators would be more useful.

Comment: That answers one question, what about the end-point (whether or not it is given) and the infinite size of the result? Since there is no significant restriction on m there are infinitely many first-steps for the paths, not to mention for the complete paths.

Comment: the starting point (in first quadrant) is given. the stopping point can be any of the points  on x-axis. (i.e. for a grid 4x4, 4 stopping points are possible from any given starting point)

Comment: If the end point is always in first quadrant, and the y co-ordinate of each subsequent point in path keeps on decreasing, there may be many end points. But the paths won't be infinite unless the grid is infinite.

Comment: Are you saying the grid is not infinite? If not, what is its size in x and in y? A large grid, say 1000x1000, will give a huge result for a starting point like (1,10) and is still not feasible to put in a list. I don't mean to be rude, but you really need to learn how to ask a clear question--include all the relevant details in your first draft.

Comment: Yes. Grid is finite. I appreciate your patience. I am certainly a noob, I realise now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clarify the requirements I am working under in the docstring of my generator `gridpaths()`.  Note that I have the horizontal size of the grid as a global variable and the vertical size of the grid is irrelevant, the x-coordinates of path points can be up to but not exceed that global value, and x-coordinates of *non-consecutive* path points can be equal (though *consecutive* path points must have different x-coordinates). I changed the name of the routine but kept the arguments as you had them. This version of my code adds the requirement that the y-coordinate of the final point on the path must be 1, and it also is safer in accepting arguments.

This is a generator of lists, so my test code shows how large the generator is then prints all the lists.

```
def gridpaths(x, y):
    """Generate all paths starting at (x,y) [x and y must be positive
    integers] where, if (m,n) is the next point in the path after
    (x,y), then m and n are positive integers, m <= xsize [xsize is a
    global variable], m != x, and n < y, and so on for all consecutive
    path points. The final point in the path must have a y-coordinate
    of 1. Paths are yielded in lexicographic order."""
    def allgridpaths(x, y, pathsofar):
        """Generate all such paths continuing from pathssofar without
        the y == 1 requirement for the final path point."""
        newpath = pathsofar + [(x, y)]
        yield newpath
        for m in range(1, xsize+1):
            if m != x:
                for n in range(1, y):
                    for path in allgridpaths(m, n, newpath):
                        yield path
    x, y = max(int(x), 1), max(int(y), 1)  # force positive integers
    for path in allgridpaths(x, y, []):
        # Only yield paths that end at y == 1
        if path[-1][1] == 1:
            yield path

# global variable: horizontal size of grid
xsize = 4

print(sum(1 for p in gridpaths(1, 4)), 'paths total.')
for p in gridpaths(1, 4):
    print(p)
```

The printout shows that the point (1,4) in a 4x4 grid yields 48 paths. In fact, `gridpaths(x, y)` will return `(xsize - 1) * xsize ** (y - 2)` paths, which can grow very quickly. That is why I programmed a generator of lists rather than a list of lists. Let me know if your requirements are different from what I suppose. The printout from that code above is:

```
48 paths total.
[(1, 4), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 2), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (4, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (4, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (4, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (1, 2), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (2, 2), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (1, 2), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (2, 2), (4, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (3, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (3, 2), (1, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)]
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: Everything is correct except that the path has to be COMPLETE. ie. the end point of the path ALWAYS lies on x-axis. (ie. y=1 is the stopping criteria).
Such wonderful Implementation of generators! Thanks for that :)

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi: The criterion y=1 is not the x-axis; that would be y=0. Are you saying you want the subset of these paths that ends at a point with y=1, so I could just filter out the other paths? That could be done more quickly in another way, without actually generating all my paths then filtering some out. I believe this final restriction reduces the path count to xsize ** (y-1) - xsize ** (y-2).

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi: I modified my code to add your requirement on the final point in each path. My new "wrapper" routine also is more argument-safe.

Comment: thank you very much for clean implementation using generators. Thanks for reminding the features of the website. Shall be more careful next time.